# Default Timeout for Launching an Android App

Tags: android

Is there a default timeout when launching an Android app?  For example, if I tap on an app from the Applications screen and the app does not display it's default activity within a certain timeframe, will I get a "Force close or continue waiting" type message?  If so, is this timeout adjustable?

Comment: 5 seconds - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html - not adjustable - otherwise apps would do whatever they want and cause an unresponsive system